# how can i refresh a page on particular time in php?

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";

date("Y-m-d");

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$time= date('H:i');

if($time == '11:51')
{
    echo mt_rand(0,9);
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo "Watch the page reload itself in 10 second!";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

// in this code insted of second i wont to pass time like 12.00 then the code execute in above code after 10 second page refresh and generate number on every 10 sec and i also wont to generate 1 random number on particular time

Comment: windows but how its wok?

Comment: @WasteD What does refreshing a document in a browser have to do with a server side cron job?

Comment: Just check the amount of seconds left until the time you want to reload the page

Comment: @nikichaudhari You are much better off using client side logic (javascript) instead of using meta tags for that.

Comment: agree with @arkascha ; PHP is not meant to handle such "events", its javascript's job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your code something like:

```
<?php

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";

date("Y-m-d");

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$time= date('H:i');

if($time == '11:51')
{
    echo mt_rand(0,9);
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
?>
<html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        window.location.href = '<?php echo $page?>';
    },<?php echo (int)$sec ?> * 1000); 
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo "Watch the page reload itself in 10 second!";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you use this little `Javascript` snippet to refresh the page.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 setInterval(function() {
  location.reload(true);
 },21 * 1000); //21 is after how much seconds you wanna reload!
};
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, any code there will not get called without a request from the browser, the solution is AJAX. In your case try something like this (you need jQuery for this particular example):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"my-file.php",
    success:function(data){
      //now data is the current time on the server, react accordingly with location.reload(true);
  });

}, 10000); // check every 10 seconds (change to any milliseconds you want)
```

In your my-file.php just echo the server time

Comment: how can i genarate 3 digit number on key up of text box in another text box ?

Comment: <script>
  window.setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"gen.php",
    success:function(data){
      //now data is the current time on the server, react accordingly with location.reload(true);
  });

}, 60000);
 </script> //not worrking after 60second

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in both JavaScript and PHP , JavaScript solution is already above. Here is a PHP solution:

```
<?php

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";

date("Y-m-d");

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$time= date('H:i');

if($time == '11:51')
{
    echo mt_rand(0,9);
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo "Watch the page reload itself in 10 second!";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```